# What is the reqular expression for RFC4716 SSH2 public key

Tags: regex, ssh, sed

I need to restore the RFC4716 SSH2 public key structure after having replaced all new line characters with spaces (the key contents is passed as a parameter to the program and retrieved as $@ in bash). I would like to use regular expression and sed program to do it. Has anyone come across a solution?

Example:

- input string passed to the program (one string all new lines replaced by spaces):

  `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ---- Comment: "1024-bit RSA, converted from OpenSSH by me@example.com" x-command: /home/me/bin/lock-in-guest.sh AAAAB3NzaC1y(... some spaces are inserted instead of LF)9zcE= ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`
- output string:

  `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
  Comment: "1024-bit RSA, converted from OpenSSH by me@example.com"
  x-command: /home/me/bin/lock-in-guest.sh
  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAIEA1on8gxCGJJWSRT4uOrR13mUaUk0hRf4RzxSZ1zRb
  YYFw8pfGesIFoEuVth4HKyF8k1y4mRUnYHP1XNMNMJl1JcEArC2asV8sHf6zSPVffozZ
  5TT4SfsUu/iKy9lUcCfXzwre4WWZSXXcPff+EHtWshahu3WzBdnGxm5Xoi89zcE=
  ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`

Answer (score 1):

Does this command do what you want?

```
sed -e 's/Comment:/\n&/' -e 's/x-command: [^ ]* /\n&\n/' -e 's/---- END/\n&/' | sed '4 { s/ /\n/g }'
```

The first sed recreates the original lines, but leaves the public key as one line with spaces.  The second sed replaces the spaces in the public key (line four) with newlines.